# send calendar invitation from lotus to exchange through java domino api

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I am trying to send calendar invitation from Lotus to Exchange through JAVA Domino API.
When I send the invitation from one lotus account to other lotus account, it is successful.
But when I send the same to some Exchange mail account, exchange is not showing it as an Invitation.

The code that I am using fro this is as follows:

```java
package com.test;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Vector;

import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.DateTime;
import lotus.domino.Document;
import lotus.domino.NotesFactory;
import lotus.domino.Session;
import lotus.entity.Meeting;

import com.data.Strings;

public class CalenderTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Vector<String> sendTo = new Vector<String>();
        sendTo.add("xxxx.xx.com");

        Meeting m =  new Meeting();
        m.setDate("04-04-2013");
        m.setTime("06:06:06");
        m.setHours("4");
        m.setChair("xxxx.xx.com");
        m.setSubject("Testing Calendar");
        m.setLocation("TestLocation");
        m.setBody("TestBody");
        m.setSendTo(sendTo);

        try
        {
            Session s = NotesFactory.createSessionWithIOR(Strings.IOR, "xxxxxxx", "xxxxx");
            Database db = s.getDatabase(s.getServerName(), "xxxx");

            Document doc1 = db.createDocument(); 
            doc1.appendItemValue("Form","Notice"); 
            doc1.appendItemValue("NoticeType","I");
            doc1.appendItemValue("_ViewIcon","133.0"); 
            doc1.appendItemValue("AppointmentType","3"); 
            Session stmp = db.getParent(); 
            String[] date = m.getDate().split("-");
            String[] time = m.getTime().split(":");
            Date exdate = new Date();
            exdate.setDate(Integer.parseInt(date[0]));
            exdate.setHours(Integer.parseInt(time[0]));
            exdate.setMinutes(Integer.parseInt(time[1]));
            exdate.setMonth(Integer.parseInt(date[1])-1);
            exdate.setSeconds(Integer.parseInt(time[2]));
            exdate.setYear(Integer.parseInt(date[2])-1900);
            System.out.println(exdate.toString());
            DateTime currTime =  stmp.createDateTime(exdate); 
            doc1.appendItemValue("StartDateTime",currTime) ; 
            doc1.appendItemValue("CalendarDateTime",currTime); 
            doc1.appendItemValue("StartDate",currTime) ; 
            doc1.appendItemValue("StartTime",currTime) ; 
            currTime.adjustHour(Integer.parseInt(m.getHours()), true); 
            doc1.appendItemValue("EndDateTime",currTime) ; 
            doc1.appendItemValue("EndDate",currTime) ; 
            doc1.appendItemValue("EndTime",currTime) ; 
            doc1.appendItemValue("$NoPurge",currTime) ; 
            doc1.appendItemValue("Subject",m.getSubject());  
            doc1.appendItemValue("Location",m.getLocation()); 
            doc1.appendItemValue("Body",m.getBody()); 
            doc1.appendItemValue("From",s.getUserName());
            doc1.appendItemValue("Chair",m.getChair());
            doc1.appendItemValue("RequiredAttendees",m.getSendTo());
            doc1.appendItemValue("OPTIONALATTENDEES",m.getCopyTo());
            doc1.computeWithForm(true, false);
            doc1.save(true, false, false);
            doc1.send(m.getSendTo());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone give some suggestions?

Comment: What is `lotus.entity.Meeting`?

Comment: Looks like a bean they made.

Comment: What if you send it using Notes client (from Notes Calendar)?

Comment: @PanuHaaramo Yes, the lotus.entity.Meeting is just a bean class.

Comment: @PanuHaaramo I am able to send it through Notes client but not through code

Comment: Is this code running as client, or as an agent on the server?  What Notes client/Domino server version(s) are you using?  And what version of Exchange and Outlook are on the other end?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz This is the code running as client and the domino version I am using is 8.2. I am not sure about the version of Exchange. I am just trying to send invitation to an Exchange mail Id.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to send an **.ics** file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid1@example.com
DTSTAMP:19970714T170000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe:MAILTO:john.doe@example.com
DTSTART:19970714T170000Z
DTEND:19970715T035959Z
SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar

Here is a related question:

[unable to send meeting request from lotus notes to microsoft exchange using icalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744648/adding-icalendar-ics-file-to-lotus-notes-email)

Comment: Can you explain how to create and send this ics file in detail. I have no idea about this ics file.

Comment: @eswarjayavarapu Copy paste the above to Notepad and save it as meeting.ics. Then attach it to an e-mail and send to Exchange account. Try these steps manually first and if it works, you can consider doing the same in your code.

Comment: Do I need to send that .ics file as an attachment or in any other way?

Comment: @eswarjayavarapu Try that way but you may need to use MIME. See linked question.

Answer (score 2):

A invite.ics is correct when using a smtp server using mail.jar, in this case, however, it uses the internal routing domain and should be set all the data on the document, then we will think domino to convert and send the just mail to external addresses.

I only have the LotusScript code, but it will easily convert it to java.

```java
Dim invitation As NotesDocument
Dim item As NotesItem
Dim startdttm As NotesDateTime
Dim enddttm As NotesDateTime
Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem
Dim prompt As String
Dim language As String
Dim tasktype As String
Dim tmpItem As NotesItem

'Compute SendTo and CopyTo items
Dim SendTo$, CopyTo$

SendTo$ = "test@domain.com"
CopyTo$ = ""
language = "en"

Set invitation = New NotesDocument( taskdoc.ParentDatabase )
With invitation
    .ReplaceItemValue "$AltPrincipal", "Automatic Notification <noresponse@domain.com>"
    .ReplaceItemValue "$CSVersion", "2"
    .ReplaceItemValue "$CSWISL", Evaluate({@Explode("$S:1;$L:1;$B:1;$R:1;$E:1;$W:1;$O:1;$M:1;RequiredAttendees:1;INetRequiredNames:1;AltRequiredNames:1;StorageRequiredNames:1;OptionalAttendees:1;INetOptionalNames:1;AltOptionalNames:1;StorageOptionalNames:1"; ";")})
    .ReplaceItemValue "$HFFlags", "1"
    .ReplaceItemValue "$IconSwitcher", "Meeting"
    .ReplaceItemValue "$Mailer", "FL Mailer 1.0"
    .ReplaceItemValue "$MiniView", "1"
    .ReplaceItemValue "$NameLanguageTags", "en"
    .ReplaceItemValue "$PublicAccess", "1"
    .ReplaceItemValue "$SMTPKeepNotesItems", "1"
    .ReplaceItemValue "$StorageCc", ""
    .ReplaceItemValue "$StorageTo", "1"
    .ReplaceItemValue "$TableSwitcher", "Description"
    .ReplaceItemValue "$WatchedItems", Evaluate({@Explode("$S;$L;$B;$R;$E;$W;$O;$M;RequiredAttendees;INetRequiredNames;AltRequiredNames;StorageRequiredNames;OptionalAttendees;INetOptionalNames;AltOptionalNames;StorageOptionalNames"; ";")})
    .ReplaceItemValue "AltChair", "Automatic Notification <noresponse@domain.com>"
    .ReplaceItemValue "AltCopyTo", ""
    .ReplaceItemValue "AltRequiredNames", SendTo$
    .ReplaceItemValue "AltSendTo", SendTo$
    .ReplaceItemValue "AppointmentType", "3"        
    .ReplaceItemValue "ApptUNID", .UniversalID
    .ReplaceItemValue "Broadcast", "1"
    .ReplaceItemValue "Categories", ""
    .ReplaceItemValue "Chair", "Notifiche Automatiche"
    .ReplaceItemValue "CopyTo", CopyTo$         
    .ReplaceItemValue "CWeSigProcessed", "Y"
    .ReplaceItemValue "Encrypt", "0"
    .ReplaceItemValue "DisplayCopyTo_Icon", "1"
    .ReplaceItemValue "Form", "Notice"      
    .ReplaceItemValue "Importance", "2"     
    .ReplaceItemValue "InetCopyTo", CopyTo$     
    '.ReplaceItemValue "INetFrom", "Automatic Notification"
    .ReplaceItemValue "INetRequiredNames", SendTo$
    .ReplaceItemValue "INetSendTo", SendTo$             
    .ReplaceItemValue "IsBroadcast", "0"
    .ReplaceItemValue "NoticeType", "I"
    .ReplaceItemValue "OnlinePlace", ""
    .ReplaceItemValue "OrgTable", "C0"
    .ReplaceItemValue "PreventCounter", "1"
    .ReplaceItemValue "PreventDelegate", ""
    .ReplaceItemValue "Principal", "Automatic Notification <noresponse@domain.com>"
    .ReplaceItemValue "RequiredAttendees", SendTo$
    .ReplaceItemValue "ReturnReceipt", ""
    .ReplaceItemValue "SchedulerSwitcher", "1"
    .ReplaceItemValue "SendTo", SendTo$
    .ReplaceItemValue "SequenceNum", 1
    .ReplaceItemValue "Sign", ""
    .ReplaceItemValue "StorageequiredNames", "1"
    .ReplaceItemValue "STRecordMeeting", ""
    .ReplaceItemValue "Subject", "Broadcast: " + taskdoc.nome(0)
    .ReplaceItemValue "Topic", taskdoc.nome(0)
    .ReplaceItemValue "UpdateSeq", 1
    .ReplaceItemValue "WebDateTimeInit", "1"
    .ReplaceItemValue "_ViewIcon", 133      
End With

Dim tmpDate As NotesDateTime
Dim itemData As NotesItem   
Dim itemOra As NotesItem
Dim itemTemp As NotesItem
Dim appDescription As NotesRichTextItem

Set tmpDate = New NotesDateTime(itemData.Datetimevalue.DateOnly + " " + itemOra.Datetimevalue.TimeOnly)
Call invitation.Replaceitemvalue("CalendarDateTime", tmpDate)
Call invitation.Replaceitemvalue("StartDateTime", tmpDate)
Call invitation.Replaceitemvalue("StartTimeZone", "Z=-1$DO=1$DL=3 -1 1 10 -1 1$ZX=97$ZN=W. Europe") ' FIX WITH CORRECT TIME ZONE

Set tmpDate = New NotesDateTime(itemData.Datetimevalue.DateOnly + " " + itemOra.Datetimevalue.TimeOnly)
Call tmpDate.AdjustHour( 1 , True )
Call invitation.Replaceitemvalue("EndDateTime", tmpDate)
Call invitation.Replaceitemvalue("EndTimeZone", "Z=-1$DO=1$DL=3 -1 1 10 -1 1$ZX=97$ZN=W. Europe") ' FIX WITH CORRECT TIME ZONE

Set tmpDate = New NotesDateTime(itemData.Datetimevalue.DateOnly + " " + itemOra.Datetimevalue.TimeOnly)
Call tmpDate.SetAnyTime
Set itemTemp = invitation.Replaceitemvalue("EndDate", "")
Set itemTemp.DateTimeValue = tmpDate

Set tmpDate = New NotesDateTime(itemData.Datetimevalue.DateOnly + " " + itemOra.Datetimevalue.TimeOnly)
Call tmpDate.AdjustHour( 1 , True )
Call tmpDate.SetAnyDate
Set itemTemp = invitation.Replaceitemvalue("EndTime", "")
Set itemTemp.DateTimeValue = tmpDate    

' NoPurge
invitation.ReplaceItemValue "$NoPurge", invitation.StartDateTime

'Send the invitation and save ApptUNID on the task doc
Call Invitation.Send(False)
If taskdoc.ApptUNID(0) = "" Then
    TaskDoc.ApptUNID = invitation.UniversalID
    Call TaskDoc.Save(True, False)
End If
```